# Create new photos from a photo based on variations of an adjustment

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, photoshop-effects, photoshop-scripting

I have a picture here and I want to apply an adjust (brightness for example) and save like 40 pictures, each one with a different level of brightness. Is there a way to do this automatically?
I use gimp and Photoshop.

Comment: How would it do it automatically, if you are doing a different adjustment? (or are the pictures different levels - but doing the *same* adjustment)

Answer (score 1):

Not Gimp or Photoshop, but using ImageMagick, a command-line toolbox:

```
for b in $(seq -w 2 2 80);do convert in.jpg -brightness-contrast +$b out-$b.jpg;done
```

The above command works in Linux and should work on OS/X, and in Windows there is an equivalent `FOR /L %%parameter IN (start,step,end) DO` command. In recent versions of ImageMagick, use `magick convert` instead of `convert`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This took me a lot of efford...

First you save the code at the bottom as AddNumberPng.jsx, or whatever you want in the Photoshop Scripts Folder.

Now edit the code and change the directory to your desired folder. In the code below it is "~/Desktop/MacWin".

Restart the Photoshop just in case it is open.

Create a new adjustment Layer. In my exemple I created a Brightness/contrast with a brightness value of 5.

[image]

With the adjustment Layer selected, Create a new Action.

Press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>J</kbd>  to duplicate the adjustment Layer. This will increase its value.

Go to Menu > File > Scripts> AddNumberPng.

Stop recording the Action.

[image]

Everytime you play this action your file will be saved in the desired folder with a name0001.png, name0002.png… and increasing the adjustment effect by 5.

The code:

```
    #target photoshop  
app.bringToFront();  
main();  
function main(){  
if(!documents.length) return;  
//amend to suit  
var folderPath = Folder("~/Desktop/MacWin");  //You can change this directory
if(!folderPath.exists) {  
    alert("Output folder does not exist!");  
    return;  
    }  
//this should be the first part of the filename   
//I.E. if file name = Picture0001.png it needs to be Picture  
//N.B. it must be the same case!  
var fileName  = "filename";  
var fileType = "png";                           //Leó 22/02/2018
var fileList = new Array();  
var newNumber=0;  
var saveFile='';  
fileList = folderPath.getFiles((fileName + "*." + fileType));  
fileList.sort().reverse();  
if(fileList.length == 0){  
saveFile=File(folderPath + "/" + fileName + "0001." +fileType);  
activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, SaveDocumentType.PNG, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);   //Leó 22/02/2018
}else{  
newNumber  = Number(fileList[0].toString().replace(/\....$/,'').match(/\d+$/)) +1;  
saveFile=File(folderPath + "/" + fileName + zeroPad(newNumber, 4) + "." +fileType);  
activeDocument.saveAs(saveFile, SaveDocumentType.PNG, true, Extension.LOWERCASE);   //Leó 22/02/2018      
   }  
};  
function zeroPad(n, s) {   
   n = n.toString();   
   while (n.length < s)  n = '0' + n;   
   return n;   
};
```